# I can change the width of a tkinter button, but not the height

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a simple game in Tkinter and I have buttons to go to the next and last 'page' by placing and forgetting the appropriate frames. In the third and fifth lines of `__init__` I define buttons, and I am able to use `width=` to change the width of the buttons (though it does not appear in the following code), but nothing happens when I use `height=` to change the height of the buttons. Please let me know if you know why this is. There are no bugs in the code so it should run as is. I am using Python 3.3.4. Thank you.

```
from tkinter import *
import math
master=Tk()

class makeframe(object):
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.i=i
        self.frame=Frame(master)
        self.nextbutton=Button(self.frame,text='next\n>>',command=self.next,state=DISABLED,height=2)
        self.nextbutton.grid(column=100,row=0,rowspan=100)
        self.backbutton=Button(self.frame,text='last\n<<',command=self.back,height=2)
        self.backbutton.grid(column=0,row=0,rowspan=10)
    def next(self):
        self.frame.grid_forget()
        p[self.i+1].frame.grid()
    def back(self):
        self.frame.grid_forget()
        p[self.i-1].frame.grid()
    def allownext(self):
        self.nextbutton.config(state=ACTIVE)
    def disablenext(self):
        self.nextbutton.config(state=DISABLED)

def rounds(i):
    number=round(4+i*(5-p[0].numberofplayers.get()))
    return(number)

n=7
p=[0]*n
f=[0]*n
for j in range(n):
    p[j]=makeframe(j)
    f[j]=p[j].frame

# 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
def after_numberofplayers():
    p[0].numberofturns.set(0)
    for i in range(4):
        p[0].numberofturnsbutton[i].config(text='%i'%rounds(i),value=rounds(i),state=ACTIVE)
        p[0].disablenext()
p[0].numerofplayerslabel=Label(f[0],text='Please select the number of players.')
p[0].numerofplayerslabel.grid(column=1,columnspan=4,row=0)
p[0].numberofplayers=IntVar()
p[0].numberofplayers.set(0)
p[0].numberofplayersbutton={}
p[0].numerofturnslabel=Label(f[0],text='Please select the number of rounds.')
p[0].numerofturnslabel.grid(column=1,columnspan=4,row=2)
p[0].numberofturns=IntVar()
p[0].numberofturns.set(0)
p[0].numberofturnsbutton={}
for i in range(4):
    p[0].numberofplayersbutton[i]=Radiobutton(f[0],text='%i' %(i+1),variable=p[0].numberofplayers,value=(i+1),command=after_numberofplayers,width=5)
    p[0].numberofplayersbutton[i].grid(row=1,column=i+1,sticky='w')
    p[0].numberofturnsbutton[i]=Radiobutton(f[0],text='%i' %rounds(i),variable=p[0].numberofturns,value=rounds(i),state=DISABLED,command=p[0].allownext,width=5)
    p[0].numberofturnsbutton[i].grid(row=3,column=i+1,sticky='w')
# 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
p[0].frame.grid()
p[0].backbutton.config(state=DISABLED)
```

Comment: It's weird. I c/p this code and ran it with two different height values and buttons' heights changed. Are you sure you are not missing or changed anything?

Comment: Correct, and thank you for checking. For good measure, I copied and pasted this code in a new .py and ran it and the same thing is happening. However, if I make the height something large like 20, the button does not change height, but the row (well, the span of rows) that the button is in does change height.

Comment: What platform are you running this on? You have much less flexibility on a Mac because of native widget constraints.

Comment: I am running on OSX- thought that might be it. Seems strange, though, that I can change width but not height. Anyway, thank you for your response.

Comment: I run your code. height works as it should in ubuntu 14.04 and python 3.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer in the comments of the question, the problem is that you are running your code on OSX. That operating system does not allow you to change the height of buttons. Apple is more strict about allowing applications to deviate from their style guidelines.